# Electrolysis of Strongly Basic Water

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

What happens when strongly basic water is electrolyzed? I know that the electrolysis of water in strongly acidic solution involves hydrogen protons; will these protons still be involved in strongly basic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a basic solution $\ce{H2O}$ will act as the $\ce{H}$-source for the hydrogen evolution reaction. The reaction will look something like:

\begin{equation}
 \ce{2H2O + 2e- -> 2OH- + H2}
\end{equation}